# Peer to peer communication from browser

Tags: java, web, p2p

Hey we're planning to make real time video calling service (Just like Hangouts provides and only in our college **intranet** ) which only uses browser but we're stuck at a point how should we transfer data to the other client directly without passing it from server ?
 
We were thinking to use applet but you can't create socket connection from applet code due to security restrictions of java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/)

[this](http://peerjs.com/) library simplifies the management of [webrtc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) connections in js.

Answer (score 2):

Using a java applet probably is not the best choice for a number of reasons. The most important in my opinion is most modern browsers have stopped supporting the Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface (NPAPI). Why not build a simple node app? Using something such as [firehose](http://firehose.io/), a simple pub/sub server. All your client side models would be in sync with the server, therefore making it easy to "transfer data" between clients. Firehose is also easy to set up and configure.